# How do I restart when it is out of words/completed? Array! Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to restart the game / words when it is completed. How do I?
I'm trying to fix this problem but it is very complicated for me, I am beginner!!

```
var array = [       "word 1",
                    "word 2",
                    "word 3",
                    "word 4",
                    "word 5",
                    "word 6",
                    "word 7",
                    "word 9",
                    "word 8",
                    "word 10",
                    ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func changeWord() {
    guard !array.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    lblOUTLET.text = array.remove(at: randomInt)
}

@IBAction func btnNextAction(_ sender: Any) {
    changeWord()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to do when you restart - for example, do you want to load a new list of words? Reload the same list of words again? etc. - but you would probably want to implement the restart functionality here:

```
func changeWord() {
    guard !array.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    lblOUTLET.text = array.remove(at: randomInt)
}
```

In the above, where you check to see if the array is empty, if the array is indeed empty, you would do whatever you need to do to restart. But without knowing what you want to do, it's a bit difficult to provide further suggestions :)

The basic functionality might look something like this:

```
func setupArray() {
    array = [       "word 1",
                    "word 2",
                    "word 3",
                    "word 4",
                    "word 5",
                    "word 6",
                    "word 7",
                    "word 9",
                    "word 8",
                    "word 10",
                    ]
}

func changeWord() {
    if array.isEmpty  {
        // Set up the array again
        setupArray()
    }
    let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    lblOUTLET.text = array.remove(at: randomInt)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes I want to Reload the same list of words again!

Comment: See the updated code I added above if you are not sure of what to do.

Comment: Thanks! <3 It works, but if there are a lot of words/sentences, then the list becomes very long :) Is it possible to do new Func like: func IfOver  ()  {
}
only to reduce the text.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the comment, you can create a method to set up the array in whichever way you want and simply call that method from the `changeWord` method when you need to.

Comment: Is it asking too much if I ask you to fix the method? because I am trying to fix it by my self,  but i does not go so well for me :(

Comment: Happy to help :)